# How to set the Facebook meta tags when I request the page?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

How can I set the meta tags of Facebook based on the loaded content ( not using jquery nor ajax ), I am loading the content from another page which performing MySQL selection based on the id it receives through $_GET.

I mean : page X have a list of links and each link has an id which is sent to anther page to generate content by selecting data from mySQL database and then including the page in page X

What I have noticed through testing that Facebook can nor recognize the dynamic generated content while requesting the page

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you are asking. So you have a page that is running as a canvas app that needs to read the meta tags off the facebook page?

Comment: In that case, there isn't any particularly simple remedy as X-domain settings generally prevent pages from different domains (yourdomain.com/facebook.com) from interacting unless explicitly specified

Comment: no dear : look at this website :http://palestinianz.com I need to change teh meta tag based on the person you click !

Comment: So are you looking for another meta tag like `<meta property="og:title" content="They Are Palestinians !"/><meta property="og:url" content="http://www.palestinianz.com/"/><meta property="og:site_name" content="They Are Palestinians !"/>`?

Comment: yes but the content of this meta tag should differ each time i click on different page !

Comment: So how are you populating the keyword meta tags at the top?

Comment: using php variables <meta property="og:title" content="<? echo $name?>"/><meta property="og:url" content="http://www.palestinianz.com/"/><meta property="og:site_name" content="<? echo $name?>"/>

Answer (score -1):

You could either pass in the name as a param from the first page or do a SQL lookup from the second page like so

```
<?php

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id,name FROM people WHERE id=?');
$r = $sth->execute(array($_GET['p']));

echo '<meta property="og:your_property" content="' . $r[0]['name'] . '" />';

$>
```

Comment: it does not work, when I try it using Facebook debugger, it returns empty string !!!

Comment: Try this again (updated answer) I think I forgot to do array index [0] on the result set; inspect the HTML output (view source/inspect element) to make sure the content is properly populated